# Making a sublime text 3 macro to evaluate a line and then move the cursor to the next line

Tags: json, r, macros, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

My beloved [gedit R plugin](http://rgedit.sourceforge.net/) is [no longer maintained](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773308/status-of-gedit-r-plugin-rgedit-in-16-04), and the forced [downgrade solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766055/how-do-i-downgrade-gedit-to-a-previous-3-10-4-version-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) that I had been using suddenly stopped working last time I updated ubuntu.  The writing has been on the wall for a while, and I'm exploring sublime text.  I've installed REPL for sending code to the command line, and I'm trying to set up the keybindings like I'm used to them.

In particular, I'm trying to make it such that CTRL+SHIFT+R sends a line of code to the console, runs it, and then moves the cursor in the editor down to the next line.  That way I could hit CTRL+SHIFT+R multiple times to run a script line by line.  (This is similar to Rstudio's behavior with CTRL+Enter)

Googling, I found this (old) [solution](https://gist.github.com/tomschenkjr/2876337).  It doesn't work, probably becuase it was written for sublime text 2.  More googling, and I figured out how to make it almost work:

```
//This is a macro for evaluate and move down
[
 {"command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "lines"}}
// {"command": "move", "args": {"mode": "lines", "amount": 1}}
]
```

Here is what I add to my default keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/geditlike_lineeval.sublime-macro"}}
```

As it stands above, sublime text sends my line of code to the  terminal and runs it.  The second line is supposed to send the cursor down, but it doesn't work, and the macro fails when I uncomment it.

I can't seem to find much documentation for sublime text's commands.  [Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands) is the best I can find for `move`.  Is my syntax wrong?  How can I make this work?

BONUS:  How can I make sublime text run the line, then skip down to the next **non-empty**, **non-commented** line.  That seems harder -- I see that a lot of the keybindings involve regular expressions and such.

**EDIT**
My problem was that I was missing the comma between the JSON lines.  AND the code linked on that github page DOES work, if you add a comma between the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you're linking to should work in both Sublime 2 and 3 (assuming the plugin providing the `repl_transfer_current` command works for both), but isn't working because the macro is not properly formatted.

> [Edit]
>   The `move` command provided natively by Sublime doesn't take the arguments your Macro is using. Presumably that's something that is also being provided by some package if this works for you. If so, you may need to adjust the sample code below accordingly.
>   [/Edit]

As it stands, the issue is that almost (but not all) configuration files in Sublime are in the JSON format (slightly relaxed to allow comments), and the macro code as outlined above and the linked solution isn't valid JSON because the first and second command in it aren't separated by a comma.

Something like the following should work:

```json
[
   {"command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "lines"}},
   {"command": "move", "args": {"mode": "lines", "amount": 1}}
]
```

I think the documentation for Sublime that you linked to above is for Sublime 2. A good resource is the [Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/), which also contains a [list of commands](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html) (plus a lot of other good stuff).

In order to do something like this and have it keep moving downward until it gets to the first non-blank, non-comment line you would need a simple plugin

Specifically it would have to move the cursor down (using the existing `move` command) and then examine the current line to see if it is blank or a comment, and if so move again. You could then use that command in place of the `move` command in your macro.

---

For bonus marks, here's an example of a plugin that does something like this. It's more verbose than it needs to be so that it's more instructive, and may require additional tweaking (R is not one of the languages I use/know) but it should get you started.

For more information on how this works, you can check out the [API Reference](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) to see all of the internal commands you can use in a plugin.

To use this, select `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` from the menu, then replace the entirety of the stub code displayed with the plugin code as presented here, and save it with a `.py` extension (name is unimportant):

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import re

# A regex that matches a line that's blank or contains a comment.
# Adjust as needed
_r_blank = re.compile("^\s*(#.*)?$")

class RAdvanceNextCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        # Get the count of lines in the buffer so we know when to stop
        last_line = self.line_at(self.view.size())

        while True:
            # Move to the next line
            self.view.run_command("move", {"by": "lines", "forward": True})

            # Get the current cursor position in the file
            caret = self.view.sel()[0].begin()

            # Get the new current line number
            cur_line = self.line_at(caret)

            # Get the contents of the current line
            content = self.view.substr(self.view.line(caret))

            # If the current line is the last line, or the contents of
            # the current line does not match the regex, break out now.
            if cur_line == last_line or not _r_blank.match(content):
                break

        # Jump to the start of the line
        self.view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "bol"})

    # Convert a 0 based offset into the file into a 0 based line in
    # the file.
    def line_at(self, point):
        return self.view.rowcol(point)[0]
```

This implements a new command named `r_advance_next` which moves the cursor downwards through the file, skipping over lines that are wholly white space or contain a line comment (assuming my regex is up to snuff).

With this in place, your macro would look like this:

```json
[
    {"command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "lines"}},
    {"command": "r_advance_next"}
]
```

In addition, you can use a key binding such as the following. Since you mention RStudio using <kbd>Control+Enter</kbd>, that's what I used here. This binding has a context applied to it so that it only applies when the current file is an R file, so that it doesn't trigger when it's not appropriate.

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file",
  "args": {"file": "Packages/User/geditlike_lineeval.sublime-macro"},
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.r"}
  ]
}
```

For *BONUS* bonus marks, you can run the `repl_transfer_current` command directly from within the plugin command presented here, in which case you don't need to use a macro at all and you could just bind the key directly to the command from the plugin. You would probably want to name the class differently in that case (e.g. `RTransferAndAdvanceCommand` or some such) so that the command name makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah, it was the comma.  First time using JSON.  Given that JSON has basically no functionality as a language (from what I've gathered), how do I write a little program that involves `while` and `regex` -- seemingly the tools I'd need to implement what you suggest?

Comment: Plugins in Sublime are written in Python (Just configuration stuff is JSON, excluding some XML formatted files for compatibility with TextMate). I can provide a simple example in a bit (currently not at a computer).

Comment: Sample plugin and usage have been added to my answer.

Comment: That's great thanks.  I've been meaning to learn some basic python, so tweaking your code to make this work will be a good exercise.